# Storing and accessing large amounts of data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, data-structures

This is something I would like to do in MATLAB, as we process the data in MATLAB.

I have over 300 .csv files each containing a maximum of 60 columns, and 1020 rows. The .csv files contain data gathered from sensors, each file contains a mix of text and numbers. The text would be header information which gives details such as where the sensor was located, speed it was travelling, the type of environment the sensor was in when logging data etc. There are 20 rows of text and 1000 rows of integer numbers.

Each data collection system contains two sensors, which gather two different types of data - call them data_a and data_b. One .csv file contains the gathered data from these two sensors, along with the timestamps etc.

What I would like to do is have some sort of searchable structure which contains all of the information from the .csv files.

I was wondering if I could put it all in a structure? But if feels like I would need a structure which contains other structures. Can I do this? In this scheme I would have a master structure which would contain in excess of 300 sub-structures. If I enter sub-structure 1, I get my header information, as well as data for the two sensors and their respective timestamps, and so on.

I would also like to be able to pull out specific data I am looking for. For example, if I wanted all data (from the two sensors) which were in Location A, I could do `master_structure.environment == locA`

Or something like this.

I'm really just wondering out loud here. I could well be talking complete rubbish, in which case I hope someone tells me and I can look for a different approach (databases are obvious, but I know zero about them), but if I am not, I would appreciate any information.

Or, if someone can suggest a different approach, that would be great!?

Comment: I didn't read all your question (sorry), but maybe [`datastore`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/datastore.html) can be useful. I think it can handle several files in a unified way

Comment: 12 megabytes of data is not a large amount. I'm unclear as to what exactly you're trying to do with this data, but you can use a `struct` as a value inside another `struct`. This type of data organization can become a bit unwieldy, maybe you're better off using a `table` data structure, I don't know. You can index a `struct S` like this: `S(4).field`, and if `field` is a `struct` itself, then `S(4).field(6).subfield(...)`. Note that each `struct` is really an array, hence the `(4)` indexing, which you can leave out if it's an array of 1 element.

Comment: +1 to Cris Luengo. If you design/name it appropriately a relatively deep `struct` can be a very intuitive-to-navigate data structure.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the advice, I will try this approach first.